# Typescript compatibility 1.0 cannot be installed

Tags: eclipse, typescript

Hi I am getting Typescript compatibility 1.0 cannot be installed when trying to create a typescript faceted project? below is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: You tagged your question with [eclipse] but this is not Eclipse. Eclipse supports TypeScript via [Wild Web Developer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wild-web-developer-html-css-javascript-typescript-nodejs-angular-json-yaml-kubernetes-xml) without the need to add a project facet.

Comment: If you're using CodeMix, the facet is present for legacy purposes and you can ignore it. TypeScript support will just work out of the box based on the presence of a tsconfig.json file. See https://www.genuitec.com/docs/web-apps/modern-web/using-typescript/ for details on how it works.